# How to Access Web Server From Inside/Outside Network

Tags: wireless, networking, server

I've installed Ubuntu on my web server. I'm able to access the web server from my home using the ip address. I'm also able to access it outside my home network using a domain that I purchased.

The problem is that I cannot access my server outside my network without changing my hosts file. This becomes a hassle because I need to do this every time and because I've setup owncloud on my server I need to have a connection to my server at all times.

Is there a way to access my server both outside and inside my network without changing my hosts file every time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to configure DNS. This is a good start: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/dns-configuration.html . Note that the DNS server is normally a server different to the server you just configured.

Usually when you purchase a domain one of the setting is "Name server". Sometimes you can point that to your own name server (not recommended), sometimes you are forced to use a certain name server. Whatever the case you need to tell that nameserver what is the IP address of your new web server.